# Juno 6.1: Old kernel versions fail to remove, "Directory not empty"

Tags: updates, boot, grub, kernel

I'm running eOS Juno 6.1 on my laptop, and recently received a notification that my boot drive was full. My current kernel version is **linux-image-5.13.0-35-generic**. When purging out the old unused kernel versions to free up space, the **linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-43-generic** & **linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-46-generic kernel** versions fail to remove due to what appears to be "*Directory not empty*" errors.

[image]

Here is the output for the failure to remove one of these old kernels:

[image]

Also, I've previously purged the **linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic** kernel, but it continues to remain in the boot directory once I update grub. I'm also not certain as to why I have unsigned kernel versions within my boot directory. I've haven't installed any kernel versions manually. I do use the apt update and apt upgrade commands regularly.

Answer (score 1):

After continued reading and attempts to clear the old kernel versions from my boot drive, I've successfully identified a way to do this. Using Synaptic Package Manager, I marked all of the old 5.11 kernels for "Complete Removal" and applied the change. The first attempt did not clear the kernel, but created additional unsigned kernels. I then marked all of the 5.11 unwanted kernels (both signed and unsigned) again for "Complete Removal" and applied the change. This time the kernels were completely removed from my system.